# Users.labels.list: why don't results include thread/message counts?

Tags: google-api, gmail, gmail-api

First of all, this is intended to be a question for Google, not the general SO community. (I say that for the sake of clarity, not to discourage anyone else from answering)

Background: The labels returned by [Users.labels.list](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/labels/list) do NOT contain thread or message counts (i.e. the following properties: `messagesTotal`, `messagesUnread`, `threadsTotal`, `threadUnread`), while the labels returned by [Users.labels.get](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/labels/get) DO contain this information.

For both operations, the API docs indicate that the responses should contain [user.labels Resource](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/labels#resource), and there is no mention of the `list` resources being minimal, truncated, etc.

Question: why isn't the `list` operation returning fully-populated labels?

If there is a fundamental reason for this (i.e. fetching the message/thread counts is expensive), fair enough. But I could avoid a lot of `get` calls if the `list` results included the thread/message counts properties.

Comment: Who ever close voted this its not primary opinion based.  Its a fact that the method returns user labels and not system labels as that what its defined to do.   OP just didn't read the documentation correctly

Comment: "OP just didn't read the documentation correctly"  

I don't mean to be rude, but I am baffled as to why someone would respond to a question without taking the time to read it carefully, and when they clearly don't understand the subject matter  

"Its a fact that the method returns user labels and not system labels as that what its defined to do"  

Have you ever even used the API? It returns both user labels and system labels. (however, as noted in my comment on your answer, that is not even what this question is about)

Answer (score 0):

Labels come in two varieties: reserved `SYSTEM` labels and custom `USER` labels. System labels typically correspond to pre-defined elements in the Gmail web interface such as the inbox. Systems label names are reserved; no USER label can be created with the same name as any SYSTEM label. The following are a few system lables `INBOX, SPAM, TRASH, UNREAD, STARRED, IMPORTANT, SENT` you can find the full list [here](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/labels)

Most Google APIs have two types of methods list for basic information about a **list** objects and **get** used to return more detail information on said object.

> why isn't the list operation returning fully-populated labels?

The list method is populated with basic information about all of the user labels.  As for what fields are returned as developers we can only see the information that Google wishes to share.    you can always post a feature request to the issue forums request they add messagesTotal, messagesUnread, threadsTotal, threadUnread).   However in my experience list method return basic information get method is needed to return more advanced information.

*Welcome to stack we are not Google.  While some Googlers do answer questions here you are unlikely to ever get an answer to a question like "Why are you doing it like this" on behalf of google.   Answers by Googlers will always be their opinion and not related to Google.*

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to respond. However, the question had nothing to do with the distinction between user labels and system labels. Also, your answer is extremely inaccurate.

`Users.labels.list` returns a listing of ALL labels, for a given user, of both the "user" and "system" variety.

The point of my question (which was really more of a feature request for Google than a question) was that the labels returned by `list` are missing the thread/message count properties in the `Label` resource, and the only way to get those properties is to call `get` for individual labels.

Comment: That is how it works list returns basic information get is used to get more details.   Feature request to Google normally get better results on their issue forum doubt you will get much luck posting it here.

Comment: At the time of writing (March, 2019), you still cannot get counts when doing a list. You have to subsequently request the details of each label to get the counts. Very slow, costly and frankly unnecessary. The equivalent Microsoft Graph API doesn't have this limitation.